# How can i fill in the gap the border radius create with a background color

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So I started this front-end challenge from a website called frontendmentor.I am almost finished with the challenge but I'm stuck at this part.
How can I fix this?

This is the outerHTML for wrapper element with .summary_results

```
<article class = "summary" >
 < div class = "summary__results" > < h1 class = "summary__title" > Your Result < /h1>
<div class="summary__score">
   <p class="summary__finalscore">76</p >
   of 100 < /div>
   <p class="summary__descr"><span>Great</span > You scored higher than 65 % of the people who have taken these tests. < /p>
</div >
< div class = "summary__details" > < p class = "summary__subtitle" > Summary < /p>
<div class="summary__grades">
   <div class="summary__grade" style="background-color: var(--clr-primary-lightRed-100);">
      <p style="color: var(--clr-primary-lightRed-300);"><img src="assets/images / icon - reaction.svg " alt="
         itemicon ">Reaction</p>
      <p><span>80</span> / 100</p>
   </div>
   <div class="
      summary__grade " style="
      background - color: var (--clr - primary - orangeyYellow - 300);
      ">
      <p style="
         color: var (--clr - primary - orangeyYellow - 600);
         "><img src="
         assets / images / icon - memory.svg " alt="
         itemicon ">Memory</p>
      <p><span>92</span> / 100</p>
   </div>
   <div class="
      summary__grade " style="
      background - color: var (--clr - primary - greenTeal - 200);
      ">
      <p style="
         color: var (--clr - primary - greenTeal - 400);
         "><img src="
         assets / images / icon - verbal.svg " alt="
         itemicon ">Verbal</p>
      <p><span>61</span> / 100</p>
   </div>
   <div class="
      summary__grade " style="
      background - color: var (--clr - primary - cobaltBlue - 200);
      ">
      <p style="
         color: var (--clr - primary - cobaltBlue - 500);
         "><img src="
         assets / images / icon - visual.svg " alt="
         itemicon ">Visual</p>
      <p><span>72</span> / 100</p>
   </div>
</div>
<button class="
   button ">Continue</button></div></article>
```

And this is my CSS file:

```
/* Font import */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hanken+Grotesk:wght@500;700;800&display=swap");

:root {
  /* Colors */
  --clr-primary-lightRed-300: hsl(0, 100%, 67%);
  --clr-primary-lightRed-100: hsla(0, 100%, 67%, 0.1);

  --clr-primary-orangeyYellow-600: hsl(39, 100%, 56%);
  --clr-primary-orangeyYellow-300: hsla(39, 100%, 56%, 0.1);

  --clr-primary-greenTeal-400: hsl(166, 100%, 37%);
  --clr-primary-greenTeal-200: hsla(166, 100%, 37%, 0.1);

  --clr-primary-cobaltBlue-500: hsl(234, 85%, 45%);
  --clr-primary-cobaltBlue-200: hsla(234, 85%, 45%, 0.1);

  --clr-white-100: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  --clr-paleBlue-100: hsl(221, 100%, 96%);
  --clr-lavender-200: hsl(241, 100%, 89%);
  --clr-lavender-500: hsl(241, 100%, 79%);
  --clr-grayBlue-700: hsl(224, 30%, 27%);

  /* Color Gradients */
  --clr-slateBlue-400: hsl(252, 100%, 67%);
  --clr-royalBlue-400: hsl(241, 81%, 54%);

  /* Circle Color Gradients */
  --clr-violetBlueCircle-500: hsla(256, 72%, 46%, 1);
  --clr-persianBlueCircle-500: hsla(241, 72%, 46%, 0);

  /* Font Family */
  --ff-base: "Hanken Grotesk", sans serif;

  /* Font Weight */
  --fw-regular: 500;
  --fw-bold: 700;
  --fw-extrabold: 800;
}

/*  1. Use a more-intuitive box-sizing model. */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*  2. Remove default margin  */
* {
  margin: 0;
}

/*
  Typographic tweaks!
  3. Add accessible line-height
  4. Improve text rendering
*/
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/*  5. Improve media defaults */
img,
picture,
video,
canvas,
svg {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/*  6. Remove built-in form typography styles */
input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}

/*  7. Avoid text overflows */
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

/*  8. Create a root stacking context */
#root,
#__next {
  isolation: isolate;
}

/* General Styling */
body {
  font-family: var(--ff-base);
  font-weight: var(--fw-regular);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: var(--clr-lavender-200);

  min-height: 100dvh;
  display: grid;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    place-content: center;
  }
}

/* Button Styling */
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  padding: 0.55rem 0rem;
  background-color: var(--clr-grayBlue-700);
  color: var(--clr-white-100);
  margin: var(--content-spacing);
}

.button:is(:hover, :focus) {
  background-color: var(--clr-royalBlue-400);
}

/* Summary Styling */
.summary {
  --content-padding: 1.7rem;
  --content-spacing: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.summary__results {
  padding: var(--content-padding);
  gap: var(--content-spacing);

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;

  background-image: linear-gradient(
    var(--clr-slateBlue-400),
    var(--clr-royalBlue-400)
  );

  border-bottom-right-radius: 2rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2rem;
}

.summary__title {
  color: var(--clr-lavender-200);
  font-weight: var(--fw-regular);
}

.summary__score {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  border-radius: 50%;

  font-weight: var(--fw-bold);

  background-image: linear-gradient(
    var(--clr-violetBlueCircle-500),
    var(--clr-persianBlueCircle-500)
  );
  color: var(--clr-lavender-500);
}

.summary__finalscore {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: var(--fw-extrabold);
  color: var(--clr-white-100);
}

.summary__descr {
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

.summary__descr span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: var(--clr-white-100);
}

.summary__details {
  padding: var(--content-padding);
  display: grid;
}

.summary__subtitle {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
  color: black;
}

.summary__grades {
  margin: var(--content-spacing);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.8rem;
}

.summary__grades div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.summary__grades span {
  color: black;
  font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
}

.summary__grades p:first-of-type {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
}

.summary__grade {
  padding: 0.8rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

/* Responsive design for larger screen > 600 px (also calling it after all styles for mobiles have been set so i dont get specificity problems*/
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .summary {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }

  .summary__results {
    border-radius: 2rem;
  }

  .summary__details {
    border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }

  .summary__descr {
    margin-left: 1.5rem;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
  }
}
```

This is the result
[image: Result]

How can I make it so that the corner above and below the border-radius gets filled in with white so it looks like the picture bellow:

[image]

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/La2pq8gx/)

Comment: CSS works alongside the HTML that's generated from the React; while I'm sure your React, and JSX, is beautiful, it's almost entirely irrelevant to the question. Could you please [edit] to show the resulting HTML and the CSS? Until we can see what you're doing we can't really say how to correct, or improve it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by showing the resulting HTML? Isn't that the JSX that I'm rendering? EDIT: Ohh I somehow put the JSX code again on the CSS section I updated it sorry for that!

Comment: Right click the wrapper of the elements that you want help with, click "inspect element" and "copy outerHTML" of the node that contains the relevant DOM nodes. While the HTML follows the template laid out by the JSX we **a**: don't need all of it (see "*[mcve]*"), and **b:** we don't have access to the various variables that populate the JSX-generated HTML, so we'll get a different, or broken, response. We could fake the variables, we could fill out the various elements with text/content, but it's easier - and more accurate - for everyone if you just copy and the paste resulting HTML.

Comment: I updated the question with the outerHTML from just the summary_results div

Comment: Thank you! Ok, there's a problem with your HTML (also evident in the JSX, I just didn't really bother reading through it): a [`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) element cannot be nested inside of another. Also, is *all* that CSS relevant to this single component/snippet of HTML? Genuinely, thank you for the HTML, and - despite my pestering - I'm trying to help you to compose a better question, and hopefully receive better answers. Incidentally, a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/oua1q69k/) from your posted code doesn't seem to reproduce your result.

Comment: Thank you for helping me through this. I updated once again the outerHTML to include everything that's needed also added a demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set box-shadow property to `.summary` class instead of `.summary__details` class. This should solve the issue you are facing.

Comment: This kinda fixed it but I don't want shadow on the left panel only the right one

Comment: You can just adjust box-shadow property. When you do right click and go on inspect, find `.summary` element, inside styles of element you can find box-shadow property that you have set. Right after "box-shadow: " you will see small purple icon (two rectangles), click on it and adjust box-shadow property. You will see X and Y offset, since you want box-shadow only on right side of element you can set it by draging blue circle or manualy entering offsets.

Comment: Couldnt manage to make it work as I wanted but still works I guess(Also this solution makes the summary details element edges sharp again instead of being curved how do I fix that since I already applied border radius). Could you explain to me how does this work?

Comment: You can try something like: `box-shadow: 20px 8px 15px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);`

Comment: Yeah, that takes care of the shadow but introduces a new problem by making the corners back to edges instead of them being curved.

Comment: I get it, you can just move `border-top-right-radius: 1rem; border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;` to `.summary` class to solve that.